# Displaying a View beneath a WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I apologize if this has been answered, extensive Googling found me a lot of similar but not-quite-the-same situations that didn't provide an answer. I have a WebView and would like to put a Google AdView underneath it. However, I don't want the add always attached to the bottom of the window, I want it to come AFTER the WebView, i.e. I scroll through the content of the webpage and then, underneath that, the ad is displayed. I've tried many variations of Relative and Linear layout, here's one attempt as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/web_frag_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="myUnitId"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried RelativeLayout with layout_below, but the WebView covers it up. It displays if I alignParentBottom, but that isn't the behavior I want. I want it to only be visible after scrolling through the content of the web page. I'm sure I'm making a simple layout mistake, and help pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that'll be rather difficult to implement. I think you'll have to track all the scroll movement in the `WebView`, then animate in the ad when the user is scrolling towards the bottom. If the Web content in the `WebView` is your own content, it would be far simpler for you to embed the ad banner in the HTML.

Comment: Agreed, this will be very hard to implement.  You'd have to monitor webview scrolling and have a function that initiates `web_frag_ad` after you're scrolled.  I recommend you put the ad in your HTML, like @CommonsWare suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I have already done the similar thing :

1- Build your Layout like this :

```
<LinearLayout
    ... >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/web_frag_ad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="myUnitId"
            ads:adSize="BANNER" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

2- Calculate the content height of your web view after the content is rendering. If you don't know how to do this, tell me, I can give you the corresponding code.

3- Set the webView.height = content.height

So your scrollview.content will adjust to the global height webView.content+web.frag_ad.height